# Nugget Language.Ext.Core Library version 4.0.4 overriden with lower Version 4.0.0

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, version

I have a dependency requiring the usage of a nuget packaged version of the ** ** dll. This package is downloaded into .nugget in %appdata% and referenced to succesfully in the two visual studio projects. Upon building, the integrated version of the dll though, has the version 4.0.0 copied into the project folder and referenced in the appname.exe.config.

I get the following Exception:

`FileLoadException: The File or Assemblyy "LanguageExt.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e33b67d3bb5581e4" or a Dependancy on it could not be found.`

Upon investigating the .nugget folder, i found out that the .nuget\packages\languageext.core\4.4.4\lib\netstandard2.0 location were the dll is derived from, has the same wrong version nr upon checking the dll details.

How do i prevent the downloading of a wrong version or it being linked with a erroneous link?

Solutions attempted so far:

1. Search for the Language.Ext.Core throughout the project and try to find a 4.0.0 version to replace.
2. Delete and redownload all nugget packages

Comment: So, as it turns out.. the package was added to two different applications, one a dll and one the calling application. It was used only in the class library - the other having it as a unused remnant. Turns out, those remnants are copied over, but not signed..

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out.. the package was added to two different applications, one a dll and one the calling application. It was used only in the class library - the other having it as a unused remnant. Turns out, those remnants are copied over, but not signed.

Trivial stuff really, but very cryptic due to the error messaging.